# How do I wait for script to finish?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have three scripts which is invoked by the function below.
while the first script is still running the subsequent commands get called which stops my first command from finishing.

```
public static void InvokePowerShellCommand(this string command)
{
   var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
   powerShell.AddScript(command).Invoke();            
}
```

I would like to ensure that the script finishes before proceeding to the next one, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `.Invoke()` _is_ synchronous, so there's nothing to do at that level. Is it possible you're introducing concurrency elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the call, a really simple example would be

```
    private static PSInvocationState state;
    public static void InvokePowerShellCommand(this string command)
    {
        state = PSInvocationState.NotStarted;
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.InvocationStateChanged += new EventHandler<PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs>(InvocationStateChanged);
        ps.AddScript(command);
        ps.Invoke();
        while (state == PSInvocationState.Running)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

    }

    static void InvocationStateChanged(object sender, PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        state = e.InvocationStateInfo.State;
    }
```

Comment: The `.Invoke()` method is _synchronous_, so no extra effort is required - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke

Comment: True, it should have been InvokeAsync in the example.  If you are calling the function from a button, then it will hold up the interface whilst running.  I will update the example